# .htaccess URL rewrite with no query string variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have to rewrite the following URLs, can someone please suggest the contents of a .htaccess file that will do this.

For example:

`example.com/retrieve_cat.php?subcat=364&c=134`

needs to look like:

`example.com/category/subcategory/`

Is it possible to rewrite this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^retrieve_cat.php?subcat=(.*)&c=(.*) $2/$1/
```